# c++ - char explanation - char explanation

Tags: c++

I need an explanation please, I want to insert a sentence, and then do all kinds of actions on it.
My problem is that when I try to print the sentence I wrote, he prints only the first word.
I do not want to use the string, except in the form I wrote.

```
int size = 10;
char* str = new char[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    str[i] = NULL;
}

cin >> str;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << str[i];
}
```

input:

```
abcdef abc
```

output:

```
abcdef
```

When I set the array of char * how it looks, like that?

char* str = new char[10]; >>> [pointer?][garbage?][Something else?][][][][][][][]

thank's.

Comment: " My problem is that when I try to print the sentence I wrote, he prints only the first word." That's because `>>` breaks at whitespace.

Comment: 10 is awfully small for user input. You're almost certainly writing off the end of what you've allocated, invoking undefined behavior. It would be a much better idea to use `std::string`.